# Using css in a MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a MVC application in asp.net , in my view I have a table :

```
  <table width="100%" class="personRow">

     <tr class="personRowHeader">

       <td style="width: 40%;"> Subiect </td> ...
```

and for table i use style personRow , an for rows personRowHeader defined like this :

```
 table.personRow
 {
background-color:#EEEEEE;
border:2px solid white;
 }

 table.personRow tr.personRowHeader 
 {
    border-bottom-color  : #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-style  : solid;
    border-bottom-width: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
 }
```

When I use only personrow the setting for table in design of my page take the modifications , but when I use the setting for my row  nothing happen.Can somebody tell me why doesn't work the setting for rows ?

Comment: Use something like Firebug (any other web debugger) to inspect those elements, most likely you have some other style that's interfering with your `.personRow` class.

Answer (score 1):

I put your code in jsfiddle, replaced only the colors with more visible colors, but I see nothing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/e9wvY/1/

Check it out yourself, everything is working as intended.

Comment: Yes , I checked myself all table code and in this site look's fine but in my applycation still doesnt't work .My page have a muster page .I will ckeck this page.Strage is that if i write code like this looks good: <table width="100%" class="personRow"> <tr style=" border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF;border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: medium; font-weight: bold;background-color: #CCCCFF;"> <td style="width: 40%;"> Subiect </td>

Answer (score 0):

give this a try and let me know it it worked for you:

```
<table width="100%" class="personRow">

     <tr>

       <td style="width: 40%;"> Subiect </td> .
```

for your css, use this block

```
 table.personRow
 {
background-color:#EEEEEE;
border:2px solid white;
 }

 table.personRow tr 
 {
    border-bottom-color  : #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom-style  : solid;
    border-bottom-width: medium;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
 }
```

What we have done so far is removing the need to explicitly use class attribute from your TRs, and instead, let the CSS manage it by pointing out that any `TR` under a `table` that has a `class of "personRow"`, should use this style

Comment: I modified but still nothing changed :(